# How to clear use of error template after correcting erroneous cell values?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I have a DataGrid in which the cell values are validated. To visualize invalid values I have a style if Validation.HasError property is set to true:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="ArialMT"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="4,0,0,0" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Text="!" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value=""/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="textBlockErrStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have `ValidationRule` implemented (I wnated to combine it with `IDataErrorInfo`):

```
public class CycleValidationRule : ConfigToolValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        BindingGroup group = (BindingGroup)value;
        StringBuilder error = null;
        foreach (var item in group.Items)
        {
            if (!(item is IDataErrorInfo))
            {
                continue;
            }
            error = (StringBuilder)base.Validate(item, cultureInfo).ErrorContent;
            IDataErrorInfo info = item as IDataErrorInfo;

            if (info != null)
            {
                if (error == null)
                {
                    error = new StringBuilder();
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.Error))
                {
                    error.Append((error.Length != 0 ? Environment.NewLine : "") +  info.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error?.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error?.ToString()) )
            return new ValidationResult(true, error.ToString());
        else
            return new ValidationResult(true, "");

    }
}
```

...and the IDataErrorInfo implementation in the model class:

```
// What is this method for at all???
string IDataErrorInfo.Error
{
    get
    {
        StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TagName))
        //{
        //    error.Append("Name cannot be null or empty");
        //}
        //if (!int.TryParse(Cycle.ToString(), out int i))
        //{
        //    error.Append("Cycle should be an integer value.");
        //}

        return error.ToString();
    }
}

string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
        // apply property level validation rules
        if (columnName == "TagName")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TagName))
            {
                //return "Name cannot be null or empty";
                errors.Append((errors.Length != 0 ? Environment.NewLine : "") + "Tag name cannot be null or empty.");
            }
            if(TagName.Contains(";"))
            {
                errors.Append((errors.Length != 0 ? Environment.NewLine : "") + "Tag name may not contain the character ';'.");
            }
        }

        if (columnName == "Cycle")
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(Cycle.ToString(), out int i))
            {
                //return "Cycle should be an integer value.";
                errors.Append((errors.Length != 0 ? Environment.NewLine : "") + "Cycle should be an integer value.");
            }
            if (Cycle.Contains(";"))
            {
                errors.Append((errors.Length != 0 ? Environment.NewLine : "") + "Cycle may not contain the character ';'.");
            }
        }

        if (columnName == "Source")
        {
                //return "Source must not be empty";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Source))
            {
                errors.Append((errors.Length != 0 ? Environment.NewLine : "") + "Source must not be empty.");
            }
            if (Source.Contains(";"))
            {
                errors.Append((errors.Length != 0 ? Environment.NewLine : "") + "Source may not contain the character ';'.");
            }
        }

        return errors.ToString();
    }
}
```

The definition for the DataGrid in the XAML (extract):

```
    <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
        <local:CycleValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
    </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TagName" Header="Tag name" Width="*" 
                                Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=RawTag.TagName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBlockErrStyle}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TagCycle" Header="Cycle" 
                                Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=RawTag.Cycle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBlockErrStyle}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TagSource" Header="Source" Width="*" 
                                Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=RawTag.Source, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                                ElementStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBlockErrStyle}"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
```

Displaying the error case works well but the row is not displayed in normal style when the invalid values have been corrected.
What do I have to do to diplays the row in standard style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` from the bindings, e.g.:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TagName" Header="Tag name" Width="*" 
                    Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=RawTag.TagName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBlockErrStyle}"/>
```

The `DataGrid` commits values row-by-row.

Comment: No, that doesn't help. The faulty row is still displayed as erroneous. Furthermore, when removing UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged it it happens that when entering more invalid values in other rows that these rows are not shown as faulty.

Comment: @du-it: It works for me. Please provide a [minimal but full repo of your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question.

Comment: I'm sorry. It works like a charme. I don't know why it didn't work a while ago. :-)

Comment: But now there's another misbehaviour: Now it is impossible to enter 'invalid' values in different rows. Or: I can enter invalid values but the row and cell are not displayed as erroneous anymore. They stay in default style.

Comment: I changed it to use: UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True .. it works pretty good now but one thing is weired: when I create multiple faulty rows and correct them, only the first created faulty row keeps its red border (the cell itself has no more red background like as if in error mode).

Comment: And what's strange is as well is that when I enter an invalid character, the row/cell is displayed like the ErrorTemplate is style. When I want to remove this invalid character to let the row/cell be displayed in normal style, I have to do this twice! Sfter first deletion and click into another cell, the character comes back and I have to remove it one more time.

Comment: This helped:
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <!-- ... -->
</DataGrid>